# How to convert the following data to table format?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 column data in the following format where Name is a string and Location is an array seperated with commas

**Name**------**Location**
John---------A,B,C,D
Paul----------E,F,G,H

I want to convert it to the following format

**Name**--------**Location**
John-----------A
John-----------B
John-----------C
John-----------D
Paul------------E
Paul------------F

Can someone suggested how can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. One option is to use `Split`, along the following lines:

```
Location = "A,B,C,D"
LocationList = Split(Location, ",")
```

That will populate `LocationList` with an array of individual locations. You can then loop through the individual locations and generate your output.

Comment: Thanks. I would give that a try.